# creating new columns based off where conditions of existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

i have a table that has everyone's email address only once next to their Member ID but i want to create columns that has their leadership email addresses in the same row.

Table 1

```
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| member_id | name   | Email    | Dir_ID   | Leader_ID| 
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+----------
|       105 | Andri  |    em100 |     106  |   110    |
|       106 | Steve  |     em10 |    Null  |   Null
|       110 | Soraya |    em101 |     110  |   110
|       111 | Eva    |     em20 |     110  |   105
|       112 | Sonia  |     em40 |     105  |   111
```

i'm trying to accomplish the following

Query/Generated Table

```
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+-------------+
| member_id | name   | Email    | Dir_Email| Leader_EMail| 
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+-------------+
|       105 | Andri  |    em100 |     em10 |   em101     |
|       106 | Steve  |     em10 |     Null |   Null
|       110 | Soraya |    em101 |     em10 |   em10
|       111 | Eva    |     em20 |    em101 |   em100
|       112 | Sonia  |     em40 |     em100|   em20
```

any info of where to start would be appreciated. i was thinking of creating a dim table and then doing a few joins but figured there has to be an easier way.

Comment: I think you may need to give us JUST A LITTLE more information. Where are you getting the `Dir_Email` and `Leader_EMail` from

Comment: So you want to change table 1 to be table 2. Am I right ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry it's probably not clear but the `Member_Id` is the unique code to each individual, everyone will show up there, the `Dir_ID`& `Leader_ID`come are just the `member_id's` of the hierarchy

Comment: Still clear as mud

Comment: Are these 2 existing tables that you want to query?

Comment: @RiggsFolly basically was trying the concept of Self Join, still learning and didn't know it was a thing. Thanks for asking but i think i got it cleared up. i'm just joining the table on itself to find `emai` l `from member_id = Leader_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an  hierarchical relationship based  on a self join

```
   select a.member_id, a.name, a.Email, b.Dir_Email, a.Leader_ID
   from myTable as a 
   left join my_table b on a.dir_id = b.member_id
```

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming that the OP wants to create 2 new columns in an existing table and remove 2  existing columns?

Comment: @scaisedge, are you saying i have to create the table b?  or can join on a table on itself?  the second table is a query or product i'd like to produce from table 1

Comment: No @AsimAhmed, is the same table `myTable` but using alias `a` and `b` to perform a `SELF JOIN`

Comment: @AsimAhmed   .. is like suggested by  Juan Carlos Oropeza .. is a self join  alias is the same table used  two time